# internal link support in mupdf

Tags: android, pdf, mupdf

I like to know that mupdf supports internal links in pdf and also it provides single page mode support for horizontal scrolling of pages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, MuPDF supports internal links (annotations with 'GoTo' type). If internal links are done with magic Javascript, then this is not supported in the current release, but work is ongoing, so hopefully this should be supported in the current development release (and in the tech preview on mupdf.com now). A proper release incorporating this functionality is scheduled for February 2013.

"Single page mode support for horizontal scrolling of pages" - I don't really understand what you mean here.

To give my standard spiel: MuPDF is a core set of libraries for loading, manipulating and rendering PDF, XPS etc files. Coupled with this, we have various example tools, which are implemented as fairly thin layers above this. These tools include example viewers for Windows/Linux/MacOSX/Android etc.

So, the simple answer is that the libraries almost unquestionably support what you want, but the example viewers may not do. But they can probably have such functionality added.

Certainly if you look at something like the Android viewer you can zoom into pages and then pan left and right across them. Is that what you mean?

Comment: i like to know that is it possible view pdf like
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.reader.lite&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwidWRrLmFuZHJvaWQucmVhZGVyLmxpdGUiXQ..
this using mupdf....